# Homebrew won't install on Big Sur (OS X 11.1) (M1)

Tags: installation, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to install Homebrew on my OSx 11.1

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

But I get the following error:

`curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version /bin/bash: not found`

I found similar errors reported when trying to install Homebrew on old OSX systems, but this is not the case here. Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the system tools here.  `which curl` returned:

```
/opt/local/bin/curl
```

So I tried reducing the installer's `PATH` to the basics with the code below:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin /bin/bash -c "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Than added Homebrew to my `PATH` in `/Users/hatvaniistvan/.profile` with

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> Users/hatvaniistvan/.profile

eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

This solved the problem and I managed not just install, but update homebrew as well.

Comment: This answer may be correct, but it will be clearer if you add it to the explanation about it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I expanded on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your curl is somehow linked to an older version(like macports). check the curl path and make sure you are using /usr/bin/curl.